# Cannot get LL(1) form of grammar for recursive descent parser

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, recursive-descent, ambiguous-grammar

I have grammar:

```
S -> bU | ad | d
U -> Ufab | VSc | bS
V -> fad | f | Ua
```

To contruct recursive descent parser I need LL(1) form.
Best I got is:

```
S -> bU | ad | d
U -> fY | bSX
Y -> adScX | ScX
X -> fabX | aScX | ε
```

Removed left recursions and done some left factoring but I am stuck.
Tried for several hours but I cannot get it...

E.g. valid string are:

- bbdfabadc
- bbdfabfabfabfab
- bfadadcfabfab
- bbadaadc
- bfbbdfabc

Obviously my grammar form is ambiguous for some so I cannot make recursive descent parser...

From answer:

```
S -> bU | ad | d
U -> fYZ | bSZ
X -> fab | aSc
Y -> adA | bUc | dc
Z -> ε | XZ
A -> Sc | c
```

Still not LL(1). First and follow for Z are not disjoint.

Answer (score 0):

Generally to make a grammar LL(1) you'll need to repeatedly left factor and remove left recursion until you've managed to get rid of all the non-LL things.  Which you do first depends on the grammar, but in this case you'll want to start with left factoring

To left factor the rule

```
U -> Ufab | VSc | bS
```

you need to first substitute V giving

```
U -> Ufab | fadSc | fSc | UaSc | bS
```

which you then left factor into

```
U -> UX | fY | bS
X -> fab | aSc
Y -> adSc | Sc
```

now U is simple enough that you can eliminate the left recursion directly:

```
U -> fYZ | bSZ
Z -> ε | XZ
```

giving you

```
S -> bU | ad | d
U -> fYZ | bSZ
X -> fab | aSc
Y -> adSc | Sc
Z -> ε | XZ
```

Now you still have a left factoring problem with Y so you need to substitute S:

```
Y -> adSc | bUc | adc | dc
```

which you left factor to

```
Y -> adA | bUc | dc
A -> Sc | c
```

giving an almost LL(1) grammar:

```
S -> bU | ad | d
U -> fYZ | bSZ
X -> fab | aSc
Y -> adA | bUc | dc
Z -> ε | XZ
A -> Sc | c
```

but now things are stuck as the epsilon rule for Z means we need FIRST(X) and FOLLOW(Z) to be disjoint (in order to decide between the two Z rules).  This is generally indicative of a non-LL language, as there's some trailing context that could be associated with more than one rule (via the `S -> bU -> bbSZ -> bbbUZ -> bbbbSZZ` exapansion chain -- trailing Zs can be recognized but either might be empty).  Often times you can still recognize this language with a simple recursive-descent parser (or LL-style state table) by simply resolving the Z ambiguity/conflict in favor of the non-epsilon rule.

Comment: `Z -> ε | XZ`
Isn't here first and follow clash?
`FIRST(Z) -> f, a, ε`
`FOLLOW(Z) -> f, a, c, $`